# Either or in compound statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I think this might be a silly question, but I'm confused. Please help me to understand it.

Statement is:

> Randy studies German on either Tuesday or Friday.

How should I write this as compound statement?

What I have done is

> p: Randy studies German on Tuesday
>
> q: Randy studies German on Friday

So compound statement would `p v q` is it correct?

Comment: I don't know what I can say to help you understand it, but yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: @David: one of my friend suggested me `(~p ^ q) V (p ^ ~q)`. Is it right or my one?

Comment: In mathematics "or" always means one or the other or both.  Randy might study German both days.  You are right.  If it said "Randy studies German on either Tuesday or Friday but not both" then your friend would be right, but it doesn't say this.